# How to flag (mark) email as important with procmail

Tags: email, automation, mutt, procmail

How to flag (mark) an email which matches a rule as important (press `F` in mutt will flag email as *important*). So how to write this in procmail recipe ? If procmail can not flag email as important, then is there any other solution to do this with a rule automatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no worries with procmail you can do almost everything:-)

to have emails flagged with `!` they must be tagged by `X-Status: F`

this can be achieved by piping the email through formail with proper args as shown in this .procmailrc snippet:

```
:0 fh
* ^TOsome@email.address
| formail -I"X-Status: F"
```

Comment: For efficiency, you probably want to change the flags to `:0 fh` i.e. only pipe the headers to `formail`.

Comment: thanks, I've looked at the man page. it appears 'Feed the body to the pipe' ist default. I changed it above according to your suggestion.